# Using Mono to Compile C# to WebAssembly

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I am new in Mono, And I am Using Windows 10 machine with Visual studio 2017 professional version for development

I was following the steps for compiling C# to web assembly (https://github.com/migueldeicaza/mono-wasm) but most of time i failed to do due to different reasons
1) SVN download got failed 
SVN  down load is not happening (svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm)

Error:-
c:\SVNSamp>svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk'
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 504 'Connection Timed Out' on '/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk'

2)  We have ignored the above issue and gone ahead further and got error in the following section

Mono compiler:-  cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64" ../llvm-mono

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags:

- **Do we have any steps which is compatible for windows machine?. so that we can go ahead and try this.**

Comment: You probably need to look for some LLVM on Windows instructions. But it might be easier to use a Linux VM or maybe Cygwin or WSL since it looks like that project is set up for a Mac.

Comment: Could Blazor help you compile it? As I understand it, Blazor uses Mono to compile C# to webassemblies.

Comment: if you're using VS2017 on Windows then why are you bothering with Mono when you could just use the regular C# compiler? Have I missed something? Any why have you tagged MonoDevelop which is a separate IDE?

Comment: I am sorry I didn’t give full context for this.
We have an existing WPF application and having a plan to upgrade to web application. We are now exploring possibilities of using existing c# assemblies in web application, and come to know about the web Assemblies.
Now we are thinking to convert these existing c# assemblies to web assemblies(.wasm) and use in HTML. 
Here I got stuck, can you give some lead how we can convert? Is that any way that visual studio  can do this?.

Comment: Visual Studio is not the important part, it's the build engine and compiler which is key. Visual Studio uses MSBuild and the microsoft C# compiler as standard, but you can use both of those with or without Visual Studio). Anyway from what I can see from a quick google the only method to convert C# to a WASM is the one you've linked to, which uses Mono (as you point out) and is only a proof of concept, not a finished, tested product. I'd be wary of relying on it to compile things for a commercial app personally.

Comment: WASM was mainly designed for compiling for C/C++ - the idea to do it from C# is their own initiative outside what was originally conceived. Anyway if you do want to compile it I would suggest to use a Linux machine with mono and all the relevant libraries (llvm, C compiler etc) installed. You can get a Linux VM going on your PC, or maybe use the [Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) in Windows 10.